# How to create json results from mysql queries js with a one to many relationships table on Node JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I am stuck on SQL Relationships. I have been search for this solution for 3-4 hours with little progress. I have 2 tables in which I want to create a one to many relationships and i want to make a user hobbies API.

### tb_user

```
+----------+--------------------------+
| id_user  | name                     |
+----------+--------------------------+
| 1        | Irsyad Abdul             |
| 2        | Abdul Hamid              |
| 3        | Darussalam               |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

### tb_skill

Foreign Key at id _user

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| id_skill | id_user(FK)  | skill         | level              |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 1        | 1            | Drawing       | Intermediate       |
| 2        | 1            | Coding        | Beginner           |
| 3        | 1            | Photoshop     | Intermediate       |
| 4        | 2            | Basketball    | Amateur            |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I want to create a user API that return their name and their skills in JSON. here is my code

```
app.get('/user',(req,res)=>{
  let sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_user";
  conn.query(sql1,(err,result1)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
      for(var i = 0;i<result1.length;i++){
        let sql2 = "SELECT skill,level FROM tb_skill WHERE tb_skill.id_user='"+result1[i].id_user+"'";
        conn.query(sql2,(err,result2)=>{
          if(err) throw err
          else{
            result1[i].skills=result2;
          }
        });
      }
      var data = {
        'status' : 200,
        'data' : result1
      };
      res.json(data);
      res.end;
    }
  });
});
```

i want the JSON return like this on Postman

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id_user": 1,
      "name": "Irsyad Abdul",
      "skills": [
        {
          "skill": "Drawing",
          "level": "Intermediate"
        },
        {
          "skill": "Coding",
          "level": "Beginner"
        },
        {
          "skill": "Photoshop",
          "level": "Intermediate"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id_user": 2,
      "name": "Abdul Hamid",
      "skills": [
        {
          "skill": "Basketball",
          "level": "Amateur"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id_user": 3,
      "name": "Darussalam",
      "skills": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a async callback function inside a for-loop, that's why you don't get result. There are many ways to do this, but I'm just trying help you to fix your code. You can try following code:

```
 app.get('/user',(req,res)=>{
   sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_user";
   conn.query(sql1,(err,result1)=>{
      if (err) throw err;
      else{
         for(var i = 0;i<result1.length;i++){

            ( (pos ) => {
               let sql2 = "SELECT skill,level FROM tb_skill WHERE tb_skill.id_user='"+result1[pos].id_user+"'";
                conn.query(sql2,(err,result2)=>{
                 if(err) throw err
                 else{
                    result1[pos].skills=result2;
                 }
               });
            } ) (i ); 
         }

        var data = {
          'status' : 200,
          'data' : result1
        };
        res.json(data);
      }
  }
})
```

**NB:** Use [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/), It will give you much easy and accurate result